# Novice Python User having issues with simple functions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a simple python program that takes 3 inputs

1. Number of stocks I will Buy
2. Price per share of stock when bought
3. Price per share of stock when sold.

In this exercise, there is a 15% commission fee both when buying, and selling the stock.

The 4 outputs I am attempting to receive are:

1. Price of bought stock (price per share when bought * number of shares)
2. Commission on the bought stock
3. Price of sold stock (price per share when sold * number of shares)
4. Commission on the sold stock.

I am attempting to do this in a way that utilizes functions to stay organized. I realize that functions are not strictly necessary for this program, but the point of this exercise is to help me understand how to use functions a little better.

When I run my program, I receive this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 6, in main
    pcos = calcAmount(n, ppsb)
TypeError: calcAmount() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ppss'
```

Here is my program:

```
def main():
    com = 0.15
    n = float(input("How many shares are in this block of stock?\n"))
    ppsb = float(input("What was the price-per-share when you BOUGHT the stock?\n"))
    ppss = float(input("What was the price-per-share when you SOLD the stock?\n"))
    pcos = calcAmount(n, ppsb)
    pcom = calcCommission(com, pcos)
    arec = calcAmount(n, ppss)
    scom = calcCommission(com, arec)
    print("Purchase Cost: " + str(pcos) + "\nPurchase Commission: " + str(pcom) + "\nAmount Received from Sale: " + str(arec) + "\nSelling Commission: " + str(scom))
# Ask for share #,PSS bought, and PSS sold.

def calcAmount(n,ppsb,ppss):
  pcos = n * ppsb
  return pcos
  arec = n * ppss
  return arec
# 

def calcCommission(com,pcos,arec):
    pcom = com * pcos
    return pcom
    scom = com * arec
    return scom
  # Calculate Commission
```

The indention when copying / pasting to stack overflow ended up a little wonky. I'm not sure how to fix that.

I apologize if there are any egregious formatting errors, I am new to Python and Stack Overflow.

Comment: You cannot return variables line after line; enclose them inside an iterable. You're also missing out on specifying the third parameter while calling `calcAmount(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def main():
    com = 0.15
    n = float(input("How many shares are in this block of stock?\n"))
    ppsb = float(input("What was the price-per-share when you BOUGHT the stock?\n"))
    ppss = float(input("What was the price-per-share when you SOLD the stock?\n"))
    # we're passing three arguments to the function, as it needs all three
    pcos, arec = calcAmount(n, ppsb, ppss)
    # same here, I've added 'arec' argument the the function call
    pcom, scom = calcCommission(com, pcos, arec)
    print("Purchase Cost: " + str(pcos) + "\nPurchase Commission: " + str(pcom) + "\nAmount Received from Sale: " + str(arec) + "\nSelling Commission: " + str(scom))
# Ask for share #,PSS bought, and PSS sold.

def calcAmount(n,ppsb,ppss):
    pcos = n * ppsb
    # we've removed 'return' statement, since code after it won't be executed
    arec = n * ppss
    # we're returning both values at the same time, and unpack them at the function call
    return pcos, arec


def calcCommission(com,pcos,arec):
    pcom = com * pcos
    # same here, instead of calling 'return' twice (which won't work)
    # we're returning both values at the same time as a tuple
    # a,b = func()
    # if function is called in this manner
    # python will unpack retuned values and assign them to a and b
    scom = com * arec
    return pcom, scom
```

Good luck with python! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was attempting to do, in the exact way I was attempting to do it. Your explanation is really helpful, and now I know I have learned about tuples! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Above line only matters if you run this in a linux shell. It tells shell
# to use python3 interpreter to run this script.


def main():
    # One of the insights of Python is that the code is more often read
    # (by humans) than written. So you should optimize for clarity and
    # ease of understanding.
    # Code should ideally read a bit like the problem-solution description.
    # That means the variables should have descriptive (but not overly verbose)
    # names and the lines should be easy to read (not too long).
    # You usually run your script through a linter such as pylint to get info
    # on how you should format your code to make it easier to read/maintain
    commission = 0.15
    num_shares = float(input("How many shares are in this block of stock?\n"))
    buy_at = float(input("What was the price-per-share when you BOUGHT the stock?\n"))
    sell_at = float(input("What was the price-per-share when you SOLD the stock?\n"))
    paid, earn = buy_sell(num_shares, buy_at, sell_at)
    paid_com, earn_com = commissions(commission, paid, earn)
    # f"" are called f-strings and are really convenient. Check them out.
    print(f"Purchase Cost: {paid}, Purchase Commission {paid_com},"
          f" Amount Received from Sale: {earn}, Selling Commission: {earn_com}")


def buy_sell(num_shares, buy_at, sell_at):
    paid = num_shares * buy_at
    earn = num_shares * sell_at
    # you can return two (or more) results if you want but you
    # need to do it once at the end of the function.
    # The pair of values is called a tuple.
    return paid, earn


def commissions(commission, paid, earned):
    """ It's good style to document what a function does,
        its arguments and return value in a comment like this
        right after the function signature:
        Calculate commission amount for paid and earned amount.
        Arguments: ...
        Returns: a tuple with ...
    """
    # Note: since you're doing the same calculation with both
    # arguments maybe it's better to condense this in a simpler
    # function calculating just commission * argument. Then you
    # can call it twice once for each case (paid, earned).
    paid_com = commission * paid
    earn_com = commission * earned
    return paid_com, earn_com


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

PS: Welcome aboard :)

Comment: Woah, thank you! I will try to use more human-readable writing in python, i didn't realize how much it cleared up confusion until after I compared yours to mine. The f-strings are really helpful, and I will try to include more documentation. I originally thought about trying to simplify the function to commission * argument, but I can't quite figure out the syntax to do so.